# Intranet online document collaboration tool for text and/or spreadsheet documents?

Tags: sharepoint, document-management

I'm looking for a collaboration tool similar to Google Docs but with one major difference:
 be able to run the collaboration document editing tool on **intranet** - nobody from outside the intranet should be able to access the data.

I'm aware about SharePoint but I heard that it is very expensive.

Also, wikis are good but they are missing two important features: **concurrent editing** and  **spreadsheet support**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSS is free.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D51730B5-48FC-4CA2-B454-8DC2CAF93951&displaylang=en

Comment: Probably I will take a look at it after I install Windows 2003 Server on a virtual machine.

Comment: We use it internally. It's not the full blown product like Sharepoint Portal Server or MOSS, but it's fairly feature rich.

Comment: WSS is a great solution.  Also note that spreadsheets on fileshares already support concurrent editing however I usually strongly discourage it, If you are doing concurrent editing in excel 9 times out of 10 you.are using the wrong app.  I try to push the users over to sql server express or (if I have no other choice ) access.  See "Use a shared workbook to collaborate" in excel help for details

Comment: ...for some definition of "free."  You still need a Windows Server box to run it on.

Comment: @ktower: True, but to carry this to it's logical conclusion: you need a physical host machine which is not free, you need power which is not free, you need a location to house it in which is not free, etc., etc. In the spirit of my answer WSS is free. ;)